# DATA.TABLE: Creating a new column in a dataset, makes the same in another?

Tags: r, data.table

I am VERY confused with the following:
Using data.table I am creating a dataframe as a copy of an existing one. Then I create a new column in the new dataframe ... and the original dataframe gets the new column also!

```
df1<- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
df1<-data.table(df1)
> head(df1)
df1
1:   A
2:   B
3:   C
4:   D
5:   E

df2 <- df1[]
df2 <- df2[,col2:=10,]

> head(df1)
    df1 col2
1:   A   10
2:   B   10
3:   C   10
4:   D   10
5:   E   10
```

Please notice that the second head() refers to the original dataframe, which I do not want any new column.
I tried this using dataframes (NOT data.table) and worked fine.

```
df1<- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
df1<-as.data.frame(df1)
df2<-df1[]
df2$col2<-10

> head(df1)
  df1
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

Plaese advice. Any help wellcomed

Comment: You need to use `df2 <- copy(df1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `copy` and the issue will be resolved

```
 df2 <- copy(df1)
```

Comment: did mention that already in the comments

Comment: @Jaap I didn't see your comments and also if I see the timings, it is just 8 secs before it.  I would count it only if it is at least 15 secs or more.  My page didn't update

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the tip .... but WHY the command df2 <- df2[,col2:=10,] does not work in the way it should???

Comment: ok, but why didn't mark it as a dupe then?

Comment: @EL_COLO  You used a `,` after that. it is not needed.

Comment: @Jaap  I didn't search for a dupe.  Anyway, you marked it. so no worries.  If you are asking me about dupes, why you didn't mark the `cSplit` question you just answered as a dupe?

Comment: Why? You do on questions I answer (which is ok)

Comment: @Jaap You started it.  I have plenty of cases where you close the questions that I answer.  It works on both ways.  You are not immune..

Comment: @Jaap Oh, I see, so this is some kind of a revenge dupe...

Comment: @akrun, same results without the `,` and same results ...

Comment: @EL_COLO  I get `df2[, col2:= 10];df2#
   df1 col2
1:   A   10
2:   B   10
3:   C   10
4:   D   10
5:   E   10`

Comment: @Jaap When I see an answer that is a sure dupe, I close it.  I was doing it in an impartial way.  For this, it didn't came to my mind that it will be a dupe.

Comment: It is certainly not a revenge dupe. I commented and started a search for a dupe immediately because I knew that this has been asked many times before. This is a very very obvious dupe. The argument that it didn't came to mind is not convincing.

Comment: @Jaap I didn't think about the dupe.  That is a fact.